# Why Is This Simple Multiplication Function Not Returning Anything When Called in Main?

Tags: c, function, cs50

When writing the following code in code::blocks, it does not produce the desired result when called in main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float mult_two_floats(float a, float b);
int main()
{
    mult_two_floats(7,7);
    return 0;
}
float mult_two_floats(float a, float b){
    return a * b;
}
```

When rewritten as follows, it does work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float mult_two_floats(float a, float b);
int main()
{
    mult_two_floats(7,8);
    return 0;
}
float mult_two_floats(float a, float b){
    printf("%f", a*b);
}
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Because you're not storing the result value and you're not printing it.

Comment: In `main`, `mult_two_floats` _returns_ something. But you don't do anything with the value returned. Neither do you print anything in `main`. So. indeed, nothing gets printed. What would you have expected?

Comment: Also, the second example invokes undefined behavior by not returning anything.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not printing the result in the first example.
Just print it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float mult_two_floats(float a, float b);
int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", mult_two_floats(7,7));
    return 0;
}
float mult_two_floats(float a, float b){
    return a * b;
}
```

Comment: Yes, after reading your comment above, I realized my mistake. I am unsure of the reason, but I believed that simply calling the function in main, as I did in my example above, was enough to print the result. A very silly mistake on my part. Thank you for your help.

I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks to @Paul Ogilvie for his comment on question and edition on my answer.  I couldn't give a comment on question, so I had to post an answer and there was no comments when I started to write this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Just get what you have done in variable and see it works totaly fine.
please look through image attached.

[image]

Comment: Please, post code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Also, this still doesn't print the result.